# using s3 for a website which includes ajax calls and node modules folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need your help regarding on serving my webapp on a server:

I have a nodejs app and I have it running in ExpressJs in beanstalk and it is working fine,
However I am thinking to use s3 instead. So in my website I have all sort of ajax calls and also I have couple of modules in nodejs folder which is generated via npm install.
Here is the link I used in aws:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

But it is not very clear about it.
I am thinking if it is doable to use s3 for this website?
Also can you please provides some pros and cons? I appreciate it because this will help me a lot on making decision whichone to choose?

Comment: We can't answer your question. We don't know what your current back-end does and therefore cannot assess whether or not it could be run 100% client-side (which is what it would have to do if hosted solely in S3).

Comment: @jarmod actually the backend is java jersy and 100% separate from UI. and I just use ajax calls to talk to backend

Comment: OK, so your back-end is going to continue to run in Elastic Beanstalk and you're simply asking if you can move the static assets to S3 (and will they have any problem making ajax requests to your Beanstalk app)?

Comment: @jarmod Yes exactly